# How to compile apache2 to get a similar setup like webfaction

Tags: apache2, compilation, webfaction

Webfaction is a nice hosting, and how they deploy web apps is genius to me.

What it does? give you (what I think) a apache2 simple binary that can be run with your user. A ~6M setup with apache binaries, log directorie, you own conf files and modules.

```
$ tree -d -L 2
.
|-- apache2
|   |-- bin
|   |-- conf
|   |-- lib
|   |-- logs
|   `-- modules
(...)
```

This is very convenient! having your own apache2 instance, you can add your modules do your settings, almost everything at user leve.

What I am asking, **¿How can I get this same setup?**. I am compiling apache2 and php with the next configure settings.

```
./configure \
    --prefix=$HOME/webapp/apache2 \
    --enable-module=so \
    --enable-rewrite

./configure \
    --prefix=$HOME/webapp/apache2/php5 \
    --with-apxs2=$HOME/webapp/apache2/bin/apxs \
    --with-config-file-path=$HOME/webapp/apache2/php5/etc \
    --enable-zip \
    --with-pgsql \
    --with-mysql
```

What I am missing is the setup size, webfaction has a 6MB for apache2 installation, and I get more than 22MB. Also would like to have the binary results from webfaction.

```
$ tree apache2
.
|-- bin
|   |-- httpd
|   |-- httpd.worker
|   |-- restart
|   |-- start
|   `-- stop
```

So:

- How can I reduce the size footprint like webfaction setup?
- How can I get the same directory structure? (bin, conf, lib, logs, modules)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is the you are adding additional modules to the compilation that WebFaction doesn't, you can see a full list of details about how the build works here:

http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?pid=9341#p9341

Comment: Like is expired, have any recollection of what to search for?